# Access icon image from html in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I access my extension icon image from modified external html page code? I mean, in popup, I can use `.` as root directory, but when modifying external page, `.` would be the root of that page, not my extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrome.runtime.getURL(path)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL) comes to the rescue.

You will also need to declare your resources as [web-accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).